# Growing Tables with aggregations

Tags: sapui5

I'm looking at creating a table that could potentially be loaded with 100s of rows. I was hoping to use the growing option that the tables provide. I have a few questions.

1. If I have a aggregation which is a total for all the rows in that column, will it be the total of all rows or only of those that have been loaded. Or can this be set with a variable etc.
2. similar to above the select all feature to tick all the rows, will this select every row even the ones not included, or will it just select the loaded rows. Again is this just a variable that I can set.

This is a first time really using any of the UI5 table elements, and the sap said this which I didn't really understand:

"Show Aggregations
Show aggregations (such as totals) on the table footer (sap.m.Column, aggregation: footer).
Do not show aggregations in “growing” mode. It is not clear, if an aggregation will only aggregate the items loaded into the front end, or all items."

Answer (score 1):

For the growing tables, by default all actions and aggregations will only be processed for the data already loaded. Your citation from SAP means that it is not clear to the end user if the aggregated data refers to the visible data or to all data.

If you want to implement something like "Select all" or "Delete All", it would be better to implement this in the backend. From the guidelines of [sap.m.List](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/list-overview/#behavior-and-interaction):

> In multiple selection mode, users can (de)select all items using the shortcut CTRL+A. This only affects items that have already been loaded to the front-end server. All other items are not (de)selected before they are loaded (for example, items added via lazy loading with growingScrollToLoad). This conflicts with the guideline that all items the user can reach by scrolling must be (de)selected.
>
> To process all items, listen to the selectionChange event and to its flag selectAll. This indicates whether CTRL+A was triggered. As soon as an action is triggered, process the items accordingly. Depending on the number of items, consider processing them in the back end.

Comment: Okay I think I understand, I would just pass back the variable selectAll as true then the backend would process all the items, rather than just the items loaded. Thanks. 

In terms of the aggregation total then. I assume the only way to display the total for all items(even ones not loaded) is by getting a total figure passed from the backend. Which I can then display underneath or is there a better more standard approach to this.

Comment: I don't think there's any standard approach to this. You can display it where you need it.